# Digit root of some positive integer is defined as the sum of all of its digits

Tags: java

I am trying to solve this challenge on an online challenge site and I am a bit stuck. Here is a bit more about the problem:

You are given an array of integers. Sort it in such a way that if a comes before b then the digit root of a is less than or equal to the digit root of b. If two numbers have the same digit root, the smaller one (in the regular sense) should come first. For example 4 and 13 have the same digit root, however 4 < 13 thus 4 comes before 13 in any digitRoot sorting where both are present.

Here is my output:

```
Input: a: [13, 20, 7, 4]
Output: [20, 13, 4, 7]
Expected Output: [20, 4, 13, 7]
```

Here is my code:

```
int digitRoot(int b) {
    int c, sum = 0;
    while(b>0) {
        c=b%10;
        sum=sum+c;
        b=b/10;
    }
    return sum;
}

int[] digitRootSort(int[] a) {
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    int[] a1 = new int[a.length];
    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        a1[i]=digitRoot(a[i]);
        if (map.containsKey(a1[i])) {
            ArrayList<Integer> temp = map.get(a1[i]);
            temp.add(a[i]);
            map.put(a1[i], temp);
        }
        else { 
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            list.add(a[i]);
            map.put(a1[i], list);
        }
    }
    Arrays.sort(a1);
    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = map.get(a1[i]);
        for(int j=0;j<temp.size();j++) {
            a[i]=temp.get(j);
            if (j<temp.size()-1)
                i++;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

But if I change map.put(a1[i], temp); to map.put(a1[i], Collections.sort(temp));, I get this error: file.java on line 24:

```
 error: 'void' type not allowed here
                map.put(a1[i], Collections.sort(list));
```

Comment: Collections.sort(list) returns void, where as in map you need to put something which has type.

Comment: It might help you, do this
 Collections.sort(list);
 map.put(a1[i], list);
it will not give you error at least.

Comment: @ssn, to correct your code, you just have to sort your `temp` list , at the last for loop(i.e `Collections.sort(temp);`). see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include this one `Collections.sort(temp);` at your last for loop this is necessary because multiple numbers can have the same digitRoot and should be put on the list sorted.

```
for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = map.get(a1[i]);
        Collections.sort(temp);
        for(int j=0;j<temp.size();j++) {
            a[i]=temp.get(j);
            if (j<temp.size()-1)
                i++;
        }
    }
```

```
Input: a: [13, 20, 7, 4]
Output: [20, 4, 13, 7]
```

Edit: about the error

because in `put(a1[i], Collections.sort(list))` the put method is expecting `put(int, List)`, but you are giving it `put(int, void)`, because the return type of `Collections.sort()` is `void`, you just have to first sort the list and pass afterwards

Comment: Thanks this works. But when I try to sort the list before putting it in the hashmap it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: because in `put(a1[i], Collections.sort(list))` the put method is expecting `put(int, List)`, but you are giving `put(int, void)`,  because the return type of `Collections.sort()` is `void`, you just have to first sort the list and pass afterwards

Comment: even doing the sort before the put wasn't giving me the right answer.

Comment: @ssn for me it is giving the right answer both ways. putting `Collections.sort(temp);`  either in first loop or second loop

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to insert the sorted value of the collection. `Collections.sort(List)`, for better or for worse, sorts that list in-place and returns nothing. Sort the list first, then insert it into the map.

Comment: Even changing that to Collections.sort(list);
            map.put(a1[i], list); gives me the wrong answer mentioned in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're over-complicating things. Write a `Comparator` implementing the sorting rules, and simply sort the values.

Since you cannot sort an `int[]` using a `Comparator`, you first have to box the values, but otherwise it's very easy, especially using Java 8+ streams.

```
static int[] digitRootSort(int... values) {
    return IntStream.of(values).boxed()
                    .sorted(new DigitRootComparator())
                    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
}

static final class DigitRootComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        int cmp = Integer.compare(digitRoot(a), digitRoot(b));
        return (cmp != 0 ? cmp : Integer.compare(a, b));
    }
    private static int digitRoot(int value) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int remain = value; remain > 0; remain /= 10)
            sum += remain % 10;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digitRootSort(13, 20, 7, 4)));
```

*Output*

```
[20, 4, 13, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to sort the array while putting in the map. Instead, you can sort it on retrieval in the last loop:

```
    Arrays.sort(a1);
    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = map.get(a1[i]);
        Collections.sort(temp);
        for(int j=0;j<temp.size();j++) {
            a[i]=temp.get(j);
            if (j<temp.size()-1)
                i++;
        }
    }
```

If you need to sort at the time of putting in the map, you should use a SortedSet as that will automatically keep the elements sorted:

```
int[] digitRootSort(int[] a) {
    HashMap<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>>();
    int[] a1 = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a1[i] = digitRoot(a[i]);
        if (map.containsKey(a1[i])) {
            TreeSet<Integer> set = map.get(a1[i]);
            set.add(a[i]);
            map.put(a1[i], set);
        } else {
            TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            set.add(a[i]);
            map.put(a1[i], set);
        }
    }
    Arrays.sort(a1);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length;) {
        TreeSet<Integer> set = map.get(a1[i]);
        for (int j : set) {
            a[i] = j;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

However, there is even a simpler way to do with sorted set, by using an appropriate comparator:

```
int[] digitRootSort(int[] a) {
    SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
            int result = Integer.compare(digitRoot(a), digitRoot(b));
            result = result == 0 ? Integer.compare(a, b) : result;
            return result;
        }
    });

    for (int i : a) {
        set.add(i);
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (int j : set) {
        a[i++] = j;
    }

    return a;
}
```

Comment: Any idea why it doesnt work if I try to sort it before putting it in the map. I tried and it didnt.

Comment: It just doesnt sort the values if i do Collections.sort before put.

Comment: You need to do it in the else part, i.e before: map.put(a1[i], list);  In the if part, there is no use sorting as it contains only one element.